# Extracting data from a HTML response - Android

Tags: java, android, html, api, http-get

In my Android app, I am accessing a website using GET requests to its API. The request returns an HTML file with a variety of user information. From this, I want to know how to extract user data, such as their profile pictures, their data and such. I would like to know how I could access and retrieve this data to display in my app.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go for **HTML Parsing to extract and manipulate** the data then go for `JSoup`......

**See this link for more details:**

http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Hmm. Do I need to convert the response to a string or directly parse it with JSoup?

Comment: You can have this .html file, and can parse it directly, or if you want you can convert it into String and then use it with JSoup... Either way is possible

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I will try it out and let you know. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to access the data you could get the api to output in in JSON format and read the JSON from your app, something like:

```
public void getData(){

          String result = "";



          //http post

          try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/download.html");
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 InputStream is = entity.getContent();

                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;
                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                          sb.append(line + "\n");
                  }
                  is.close();
                  result=sb.toString();

          }catch(Exception e){
                  Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
          }



          //parse json data

          try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                          JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                          names.add("   " + json_data.getString("name"));
                          age.add("   " + Integer.toString(json_data.getInt("age")));

                  }

          }catch(JSONException e){
                  Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

          }
}
```

Comment: I tried this - got the response from the page, converted it to a string, and then tried to parse it as a JSONArray. When I ran the application, it stopped unexpectedly. :/

Comment: Is the original page in JSON format? Did you look at the stack trace to see what went wrong?

Comment: yeah probably the output is in the wrong format, for example if you're using php you need to do something like json_encode($result) where $result could be a row from a database.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to display the HTML data in a WebView.

Comment: The question is : "...how I could access and retrieve this data...". This is not an answer.